# How to make TortoiseHg pull certain branch only?

Tags: tortoise-hg

I have cloned the default branch of a big repository and now I wish to pull from the server using the TortoiseHg client.

However, TortoiseHg proposes to pull from all the branches. Is it possible to instruct it to pull from the current branch only?

So far I have seen suggestions to:

- Setup a hook on the client side to reject pulls from unwanted branches
- Check incoming revisions in TortoiseHg and only pull the ones belonging to the current branch
- Use the Mercurial ACL extension to deny access to all the branches, but the current one.

I dislike all of these solutions, since all of them are client based. In all of them TortoiseHg actually pulls all of the branches (even in the second, where the pulled revisions are arranged into a bundle presented in the incoming revisions view)

Is there an `hg pull -b BRANCH` equivalent in TortoiseHg?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I know how to do all of this using the Mercurial command line client - hg.exe. This question is specifically about the TortoiseHg GUI client.

Comment: Have you tried doing this from the workbench?  I'm not using Hg at work, so I can't test it here.

Comment: I am using the workbench all the time and I could find any option there which would tell it to pull the current or the certain branch only.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done from the `Synchronize` area of the Workbench.  Click the `Synchronize` entry on the `View` menu or the `Synchronize` toolbar icon (2 green arrows appearing to form a circle).  In the bottom right pane, click `Options`.  Enter the branch name you'd like to pull in the `Branch:` edit box.  Finish the pull as usual.

Comment: This seem to be working. I'd suggest to specify `.` as the branch name, this way it will _always_ refer to the branch you're working on.

Comment: Just a note for others: There is a `Synchronize` entry under the `Repository` menu. That is **not** the entry you are looking for.

Comment: @GeorgeMarian ha good point. It would be much better if the one under View was called "Sync options" or "Synchronisation". That option does not actually perform the action of Synchronise :)

Answer (score 5):

```
hg pull -r <branch name>
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796908/mercurial-how-can-i-import-only-some-changesets-from-a-repository/5798221#5798221

Comment: I have edited the question body.

Comment: @Kaymar it is `-b` for pulling a branch. `-r` is for a revision. From help for `hg pull`:  `-r --rev REV [+]           a remote changeset intended to be added
... -b --branch BRANCH [+]     a specific branch you would like to pull`